# Angular 11 application is not working in safari

Tags: angular, safari, angular11

I am developing Angular 11 application. When I run (ng serve) the application it is working fine in Google Chrome and Firefox but it is not working in safari 5.1.7.

This is the error I am getting in safari -

[image: This is the error i am getting in safari]

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is simple.

Promises are only supported in Safari 7.1 and above. Your almost 10 year old version 5.1.7 of Safari is not capable recognizing an Object of type Promise.

https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise